# Converting Url parameters to object id

Tags: express, mongoose

How can Id gotten from request parameter in express be converted to object id for Mongoose

Let's say for instance

app("path/get_user_b 
  yid/:id6888",(req, 
  res)=>.{
     //code to convert I'd 
   back to object...
  }

Answer (score 0):

you can call findById function to get a specific user as bellow

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
connst Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const User = new Schema({
  name:  String,
  ...
  // other data
});

app.get('path/get_user_b yid/:id', (req, res) => {
  cosnt id = req.params.id;
  User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500);
    }
    return res.status(200).json(user);
  });
});
```